# How to set discount amount in items ordered in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I set a discount of 20$ in products. I displayed it in Invoice details. But could not display it in Items to invoice. how can I display it in Items to invoice in admin panel?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Test_Fee_Model_Sales_Order_Total_Invoice_Fee extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        $feeAmountLeft = $order->getFeeAmount() - $order->getFeeAmountInvoiced();
        $baseFeeAmountLeft = $order->getBaseFeeAmount() - $order->getBaseFeeAmountInvoiced();

        if (abs($baseFeeAmountLeft) < $invoice->getBaseGrandTotal()) {
            $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() - $feeAmountLeft);
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseFeeAmountLeft);
        } else {
            $feeAmountLeft = $invoice->getGrandTotal() * -1;
            $baseFeeAmountLeft = $invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() * -1;
            $invoice->setGrandTotal(0);
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal(0);
        }

        $invoice->setFeeAmount($feeAmountLeft);
        $invoice->setBaseFeeAmount($baseFeeAmountLeft);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I want to display discount amount here in Items to invoice as given below:

[image]